# MSSQL db JDBC performance properties

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I was trying to improve the performance of our jdbc connection to our Microsoft sql server database. I switched from the `jTDS jdbc driver` to the official `Microsoft JDBC driver` [on maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/6.1.0.jre8):

For MySQL, there exist configuration properties such as `cachePrepStmts`, `prepStmtCacheSize`, `prepStmtCacheSqlLimit` etc., but I could not find out if they also exist for `Microsoft SQL server`.

I would like to enable batch writing, statement caching and look for other options that could improve the performance of our application´s db calls.

Any ideas?

Edit: I finally solved the problem by building custom batch SQL queries of the style ´delete o from OBJECT where o.id is one of this set of ids´. This did the trick for deletion at least, which is the one thing we had to optimize right now.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988(v=sql.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt732336(v=sql.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms378877(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think the second link is very helpful, even though I did not find caching and bulk-writing as I expected.

Comment: When you download the driver there is a directory `samples` in the archive with a `cacheRS.java` that contains the following header: "*In addition, it
         demonstrates how to control the amount of data that is fetched
         from the database and cached on the client*"

Comment: Samples! Thank you, I did not know/check this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best source for that sort of information would be the MSDN article

[Improving Performance and Reliability with the JDBC Driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms378877(v=sql.110).aspx)

which includes such topics as

- Closing Objects when Not In Use
- Managing Transaction Size
- Working with Statements and Result Sets
- Using Adaptive Buffering
- Sparse Columns

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems that there is no batch writing for insert/update/delete queries for sql server, right? Only the very strange bulk copy.

Comment: If by "batch writing" you mean something like `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` in MySQL Connector/J then no, I'm not aware of any corresponding feature in Microsoft's JDBC driver for SQL Server.